# PHP - Replace quotes within quotes - regex

Tags: php, regex

i have this text:

```
$var = 'bundle:a AND id:9 _query_:" bundle:b AND _query_:"bundle:c AND _query_:"bundle:d" " "';
```

and would like the following output:

```
bundle:a AND id:9 _query_:" bundle:b AND _query_:\"bundle:c AND _query_:\"bundle:d\" \""
```

Edit 1 :

i tried with:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!_:|_: )"(?=[^"]*?"(( [^:])|([,}])))/', '\\"', $var )
```

thanks =)

Comment: and what did you tried?

Comment: i tried with:

preg_replace('/(?<!_:|_: )"(?=[^"]*?"(( [^:])|([,}])))/', '\\"', $qq )

Comment: And why isn't there a backslash before the double quotes here `bundle:a AND id:9 _query_:"` and at the end ?

Comment: is for a query and I need to have those double quotes to run the sub-querys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$var = 'bundle:a AND id:9 _query_:" bundle:b AND _query_:"bundle:c AND _query_:"bundle:d" " "';

$start = strpos($var, '"');
$end = strrpos($var, '"');

$result = substr($var, 0, $start + 1) . 
          str_replace('"', '\\"', substr($var, $start + 1, $end - $start - 1)) . 
          substr($var, $end);
```

**Warning!** I can't recommend using this code at production, just trying to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex:

```
str_replace("\"", "\\\"", $var)
```

With Regex:

```
preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", $var)
```

Comment: this changed all double quotes in the string, i'm tried change the double quotes within double quotes.

output:

   condition AND query:" condition AND query:\" query:\"condition:a\" \" " AND condition